# Updating Timezone Information on PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

UPDATE: The issue was an old PHP version.

At 13:06 EST, 18:06 UTC and 21:06 Moscow time ([source](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow)), I ran the following PHP code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('G:i')." America/New_York\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('G:i')." UTC\n";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date('G:i')." Europe/Moscow\n";
```

The result:

```
13:06 America/New_York
18:06 UTC
22:06 Europe/Moscow
```

Currently, the timezone offset in for Moscow is +3 because of daylight savings time, but PHP is clearly using +4.

This causes for me the question of where PHP gets its timezone information, and whether there is a bug in PHP.

Comment: I wonder if you are using an old version of php or something because it looks fine to me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/F57ufT

Comment: And I can actually confirm by changing the php version on viper-7 to php 5.5 it shows +4. 5.6 reports +3.

Comment: use `Europe/Kaliningrad` in old builds.

Comment: You can update PHP's timezone database independent of the PHP version if upgrading PHP will cause other issues: http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Comment: [Moscow recently changed their time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html).  You need PHP timezonedb 2014.6 or greater.  [Read more here](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/09/23/russia-2014-time-zone-changes/).